# Is there anyway to alter error code "TypeError: a is undefined"?

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling

```
let array= [
  {fruit: "pear", price: 9.89},
];

function fruitCheck(a) {
    var fruitTest = array.find(function(check) {
        return check.fruit == a
    });
    return fruitTest ? fruitTest : a == undefined ? "Where is your fruit???" : a + " is not a fruit!!!!!"
}
```

How can I change this so when a user inputs nothing, console will log ("Sorry, you didnt input anything"). Is this possible?

Comment: That error is not produced by the code shown.

Comment: a is not undefined if passed to the function, it is just empty, but not undefined. Try a=="" instead of a==undefined

Comment: I just put the array in, so it will now :)

Comment: It's really confusing when you nest conditional operators, the grouping is often not what you expect. Either use `if` statements or add parentheses to make it clear.

Comment: sorry, im new to javascript (2 weeks in). I will take that advise. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just inside your function check the parameter to see if it’s set.

Example:

```
If (typeof a === “undefined”) {
   console.log(‘error message here’)
   return; // to prevent the rest of your code form executing
```

}

Comment: You can also use `throw new Error("error message here")` instead of `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

The error is already happening in your `find()` callback. Check for the type of `a` at the beginning of your function, then you can use `console.error()` (or `console.log()` or `console.warn()`) to log a custom error message. Of course, you could also throw a custom exception.

```
function fruitCheck(a) {
    if (typeof a === "undefined") {
        console.error("Sorry, you didnt input anything");
        return;
    }

    var fruitTest = array.find(function(check) {
        return check.fruit == a
    });
    return fruitTest ? fruitTest : a == undefined ? "Where is your fruit???" : a + " is not a fruit!!!!!"
}
```

Comment: The error OP is experiencing when passing undefined to the function. (Yes, it's not in the question directly, but can be deduced from the error message they were receiving. And as you can see, it was helpful to them, and that's what it's about, isn't it?)